# Can I change title of bootstrap tooltip without hiding it?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I would like the tooltip to display time. For this I update it every somemany seconds but changing the title every time.

```
$(".track a").tooltip('hide');
$(".track a").data('tooltip').options.title = time;
$(".track a").tooltip('show');
```

This works but the tooltip is flickering but without the hide and show the tooltip doesn't update. Is there a way to update the tooltip without hiding and showing it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok aparantly the problem was somewhere else.

Anyway now I use this one because this changes all the components that need a tooltip where the one above only changes one component.

```
$(".track a").tooltip('hide')
  .attr('data-original-title', time)
      .tooltip('fixTitle')
      .tooltip('show');
```

You do have to put the animation on false when initializing the tooltip:

```
$(".track a").tooltip({
      'animation' : false
});
```